# Exact search with list of values in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query of items and I need to pull a list of exact items by their keys. For example - item [3], item [5] and item [10].
I have this function:

```
    public List<Item> GetItems<Item>(List<int> keys) 
    {
        IQueryable<Item> itemsQuery = GetItemsQuery();
        List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
        foreach (int key in keys)
        {
            Item item = itemsQuery.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key == key);
            if (item != null)
            {
                items.Add(item);
            }
        }
        return items;
    }
```

Now, I want that this function will return `IQueryable<Item>` and not List. Is it possible to get those items with LINQ and get a `IQueryable` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method can be simplified as

```
public IQueryable<Item> GetItems<Item>(List<int> keys)
{
    IQueryable<Item> itemsQuery = GetItemsQuery();
    return itemsQuery.Where(x => keys.Any(y => x.Key == y)).AsQueryable();
}
```

or

```
public IQueryable<Item> GetItems<Item>(List<int> keys)
{
    IQueryable<Item> itemsQuery = GetItemsQuery();
    return itemsQuery.Where(x => keys.Contains(x.Key)).AsQueryable();
}
```